# AlertDialog based on dialog shows inappropriately

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i have an activity which is shown as a dialog, in Manifest.xml, I set up the activity as :"android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog", and it runs well; what's more, i want an AlertDialog shown from this activity, but owing to Theme of the Activity is Dialog, the display style of the AlertDialog is different from the  AlertDialog based on Activity. How should I set up the property of the AlertDialog to make it looks like the regular one?

Comment: I want a method by setting the property of the AlertDialog, not the way to add a layout file and setView() it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Context ctx = this;// your dialog activity;
TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
// get theme common dialog theme of application
ctx.getApplicationContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.dialogTheme, outValue, true);
int theme = outValue.resourceId;
AlertDialog.Builder bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx, theme);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank u so much! That's properly what I need. But the style is not exactly correct, I tried android.R.attr.dialogTheme and android.R.attr.AlertDialogTheme, they all offered a dark background, i need a light one. :)